# Python telegram bot, forward edited message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm building a dating bot through memes

Anything can be a meme (voice message, video, gif, story, photo album, something I forgot)

I don't want to create a bunch of handlers, I want to forward the message and attach a keyboard to it to react like / dislike

Is there a way to do this easily?

tried to use the forward_message function, but it does not allow editing the message, but simply forwards using id

disclaimer: I'm not afraid of hard work, but if it can be easier then why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for the [`copyMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#copymessage) method. This also allows you to add a custom keyboard.